# Почему убрали комментарии к неправильному ответу?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, комментарии

Есть вопрос [JavaScript и длинная регулярка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/682886/186083) про котов (домашние животные). Для тех кто не согласен, что вопрос именно про котов цитирую автора вопроса:

> Возьмём некий текст, в котором встречаются формы слова "кот":
>
> `бла бла кот бла бла "кота" бла коты скоты`
>
> ...
>
> То есть из исходной строки мне надо получить эту:
>
> `бла бла <кот> бла бла "<кота>" бла <коты> скоты`

И есть неправильный ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682903/186083 регулярка в котором захватывает не только котов, но и скотов, котлы и т.д.

Почему были удалены мои комментарии, объясняющие автору ответа и другим пользователям сайта о его неправильности?

P.S. Просьба к модераторам, вернуть комментарии на место.

Comment: На этом сайте комментариям не придается большого значения. Даже нейтральные комментарии могут бесследно удалить просто так, если посчитают что завязалась "слишком длинная дискуссия", так что не тратьте время на их написание. Если есть серьезные замечания, лучше предлагать правки к ответам.

Comment: @VadimTagil слишком длинные дискуссии из комментариев переносятся в чат. Удаляются спам/оскорбления или потерявшие актуальность. Нейтральные комментарии обычно не удаляются.

Answer (score 9):

Комментарии снес я, из-за их замечательной формулировки вида:

> ...то что автору вопроса и нужно было, ахаха...
>
> ...Так что вы не только регулярки не знаете, но и читать не умеете :Р...
>
> ...Если вы слепой...

Если вы хотите указать автору ответа и другим пользователям на ошибку в ответе - [стоит сделать это в более спокойной форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Видимо, ТС недоволен такой формулировкой :)

Comment: @Visman А в чём проблема спокойно и дипломатично сказать пользователю и другим о ошибочности этого ответа, не прибегая к оскорблениям?

Comment: У меня если что тоже бывали разногласия с этим пользователем.

Comment: @Visman, спокойнее, не стоит продолжать в том же стиле на мете

Comment: @PashaPash, комментариев тех под рукой нет, но их там было больше трех и вероятно даже во втором не было ни какой экспрессии. Там где показан результат работы его скрипта. Но и этот комментарий вы потерли.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в том что автор неправильного ответа включил режим дурочка + обвинил меня в сговоре с автором вопроса.

Comment: @Visman Чего вас это должно волновать? Оставьте **конструктивный** комментарий (а также влепите -1) для пользователей и посетителей, нашедших вопрос с гугла. А безумие конкретного пользователя пусть остаётся при нём.

Comment: Ну и написав свой ответ, пока меня не было на сайте, указал что мой ответ работает не правильно. тут же пришли 2 пользователя и поставили его ответу 2 плюса, а моему ответу 2 минуса :)

Comment: @Visman У нас иногда плюсуют то, что даже не работает. У меня тоже бывали ответы, которые набирали +5, и только после адекватного комментария или через время я видел, что они не работают. Ну я, конечно, исправлял их. Но сам факт удивителен. У нас иногда +10 набирают детские и не очень качественные вопросы. А иногда грамотные получают -5. Тут сообщество местами странновато и я иногда не пойму причин по которым оно голосует.

Comment: @Visman Но если у вас правильная (моё мнение) мотивация — нести знания, и вас не сильно парит (или вообще не парит) фарминг репутации, то вас это волновать не должно. Это **не повод** оскорблять автора неверных ответов. Просто констатация — "неверно/вредно потому что…".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я не считаю свои комментарии оскорблением. Вот если бы я его матом начал крыть, тогда да ;)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а за ответы и вопросы подавляющее большинство тут присутствующих голосует по принципу стада ;) Или просто пробежались и на всех вопроса плюсики/минусики поставили.

Comment: @Visman Я бы так не рассуждал об огромной совокупности людей. Иногда в ответе я увидел новую конструкцию или очень крутой подход — я голосую за, даже если ответ не помог мне или ТС. И с другой стороны то, за что я бы голосовал новичком, сейчас бы может даже минусовал. Будьте терпимей просто к новичкам. И вы можете не знать причин, по которым люди голосуют.

Comment: @Visman вы не считаете ваши комментарии оскорбительными, а я, и еще минимум 8 пользователей - считают. Тут где то рядом был длинный и подробный пост от Николаса про то, что оскорбление не эквивалентно мату, я не хочу его копипастить в свой ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash, я не запрещаю точки зрения не совпадающие с моей, но ответьте мне: Там точно все комментарии вы считаете оскорбительными или вы их скопом потерли по принципу "с глаз долой - из сердца вон!"?

Comment: @Visman Комментарии тут для прояснения вопроса и обратной связи по ответу. Всё остальное — подлежит удалению. И любой бесполезный комментарий может быть удалён просто по факту своей бесполезности. Ему не обязательно быть оскорбительным. Также комментарий может быть полезным, но уже устаревшим, его тоже следует удалить.

Comment: @Visman Систематическое создание бесполезных комментариев, лишь отвлекающих пользователей (необязательно оскорбительных) приводит к бану (сроки точно не помню, но что-то вроде такого: сначала день, потом неделя, месяц, год и т.д.).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, там не было бесполезных комментариев. Либо показана конкретная ошибка представленного ответа, либо реакция на встречный комментарий от автора ответа. То что тут в ответе показал PashaPash♦ всего лишь подстроки вырванные из контекста общения.

Comment: @Visman Этих подстрок достаточно чтобы удалить весь комментарий. А "встречная реакция" могу представить какая там.